# ros with multiple distros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a 3rd party gadget whose ROS interface is compiled against an older version of ROS.

I'm curious, to what extent is it possible to intermix clients and ROS Master from different distributions. Is there any compatibility between them?

Thanks,
Val

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252109/ros-with-multiple-distros/) by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 242 on 2017-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although it is not advisable, mixing ROS versions will work in some cases. Naturally, it depends on which versions you are trying to mix, but for at least a number of the newest releases, the underlying communication protocol hasn't changed, so as long as your message definitions are identical, it *should* work. Obviously, if the message definition changes for the newer distro, this will no longer work so there's no saying if it will continue to work.

For a more elaborate explanation, take a look at the following related questions: #q104086, #q76279 and #q37403.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1